Accessing NetLogo extensions within an extension
I am trying to develop a NetLogo extension to communicate with different LLMS (online, offline).  The LLM calls return a JSON formatted string.  I'd like to parse the JSON and convert it into nested TABLE objects, accessing the NetLogo Table extension.
Is there a way for one extension to access and use the classes in another extension?

There are probably many reasons to not have an extension depend on another extension, but the most important is that, in the NetLogo line extensions [table llm], where llm depends on table, llm cannot control/predict/enforce which version of table the user's NetLogo installation will use.  So, if llm outputs table objects from extension version v1.0, but the user has table v2.0 installed, table might not actually understand the objects produced by llm.
Instead, I would have the LLM extension output a NetLogo string containing the JSON, and then feed that into the table:from-json primitive, in order to get your table.  From there, you can process the table in NetLogo code.
If you want to process it in Java code in your extension, I guess you could run table:to-list on the output of table:from-json, and then pass the NetLogo list back into your extension.
Dealing with JSON data in Java isn't going to be fun, no matter how you do it.  But there are definitely ways of doing it that are more fun than using the Table extension as a JSON parser.  There are many other tutorials online for parsing JSON in Java, like this one, which you might find helpful.

Thank you so much.  I think the recommendations you have offered are quite helpful.  I remain interested, however, in the general question of finding how to create and return extension objects, e.g., tables and matrices.
Thank you once again.

In order do that, your extension would need to rely on the code for, e.g. the Table extension.  I don't believe that we publish the .jar on Maven Central (or similar), so you would need to configure your build tool to load table.jar from a local path.  Then, you could instantiate the table from one its constructors.  I really do not recommend doing this.  If the explanation in my answer above does not give a solution to your problem, I might be able to give better advice if you provide more information.

Let's start from the only constraints the NetLogo placed on how the actual extension-module gets visible and usable inside NetLogo ABM Simulated Worlds :

To use an extension in a model, add the extensions keyword at the beginning of the Code tab, before declaring any breeds or variables.

extensions is followed by a pair of square brackets containing a list of extension names. For example:

extensions [sound speech]

Using extensions instructs NetLogo to make the specified extensions’ commands and reporters available in the current model, just as if they were built-in NetLogo primitives. An extension must be installed for the extensions keyword to take effect.

So, only the syntax-related and location-related constraints apply here. Installation details are similarly clear.
Given you try to develop something new, the concept of separation-of-problems ought address your false dilemma. Your new Java code, if you opt to develop an extension, shall never violate the boundaries of other extensions' source code ( if it were for nothing else for the sake of principles of modularity & maintenance concerns ).
That means all your "cross"-module operations and interactions should happen either via NetLogo-level of passing arguments to and from extension modules, serving a procedural- or a reporter-role; or design either side of "cross"-extension interaction, maintaining in mind & design practice the modularity principles, incl. neutrality of (by)passing data-objects ( perhaps using ZeroMQ messaging & signalling metaplane(s) for glue-logic, that protects either side from any attempt of permitting a kind of wild crossing the extension-module boundaries of separation-of-concerns ).
